# JSONObject without title JSONArray

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I have remote JSON code on "http://www.somesite.com/json" without JSONArray like this:

```
 [
    {
        "artist":"Some Artist 1",
        "track":"Some Track 1",
    }

    {
        "artist":"Some Artist 2",
        "track":"Some Track 2",
    }

    {
        "artist":"Some Artist 3",
        "track":"Some Track 3",
    }

    {
        "artist":"Some Artist 4",
        "track":"Some Track 4",
    }

 ]
```

I cannot to change this JSON for adding JSONArray.

And i have Java code for getting value "track":

**SomeActivityCut:**

```
try {

  JSONObject jsonarray = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://www.somesite.com/json");

                for(int i=0; i < 4; i++){

                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject("track");

                    curtrack.setText(jsonobject.getString("track"));
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

This my class for getting JSON data:

**JSONfunctions:**

```
public class JSONfunctions {

    public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String url) {
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";
        JSONObject jArray = null;

        // Download JSON data from URL
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }

        // Convert response to string
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        try {

            jArray = new JSONObject(result);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        return jArray;
    }
}
```

This code called FATAL EXEPTION:

> E/log_tag﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at
>   character 0 of

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all this JSON is not valid. A valid version of your JSON should be

```
[
    {
        "artist": "Some Artist 1",
        "track": "Some Track 1"
    },
    {
        "artist": "Some Artist 2",
        "track": "Some Track 2"
    },
    {
        "artist": "Some Artist 3",
        "track": "Some Track 3"
    },
    {
        "artist": "Some Artist 4",
        "track": "Some Track 4"
    }
]
```

Then, you can't build a JSONObject if you are getting a JSONArray. I also suspect that you want an HttpGet, instead of a HttpPost, because I don't see you using body (not mandatory).
So, this is how I think you want your JSONfunctions:

```
public class JSONfunctions {

    public static JSONArray getJSONfromURL(String url) {
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";
        JSONArray jArray = null;

        // Download JSON data from URL
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(get);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }

        // Convert response to string
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        try {

            jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        return jArray;
    }
}
```

After that, you just have to iterate your JSONArray:

```
JSONArray tracks = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://www.somesite.com/json");
if(tracks != null) {

    for(int i = 0; i < tracks.length(); i++) {

        try {

            Log.d("track@" + i, tracks.getJSONObject(i).getString("track"));
        } 
        catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```